# How to centre align rotated yticklabels in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alignment, seaborn

I am trying to plot a confusion matrix through seaborn but unable to centre align the yticklabels when they are rotated to 90 deg. Though *ha* works without rotation but fails with rotation. Here is the minimal working example -

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmat = np.matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

sns.heatmap(cm_greina, annot=True, xticklabels=['Faulty', 'Healthy'], cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(['Faulty', 'Healthy'], rotation=90, ha='center')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try adding `rotation_mode='anchor'`

Comment: Perfect! That worked! Thanks for a prompt response.

Comment: Will one of you post an answer so this question gets closed out?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of horizontal alignment you probably want to use vertical alignment:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmat = np.matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

sns.heatmap(cmat, annot=True, xticklabels=['Faulty', 'Healthy'], cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(['Faulty', 'Healthy'], va='center', rotation = 90, position=(0,0.28))
plt.show()
```